# Linked list implementation of queue in C-about empty condition and free

Tags: c, data-structures, queue, free

This is the code for deleting the front item from the queue I have already made.
I try to understand that itemPtr will be used somehow in main.. not known yet but that's not the point.
I wonder whether

```
if (queue->count == 0)
```

can be used instead of

```
if (!queue->count)
```

Are the NULL and 0 used in the same way?

To add, what does this do?

```
free(deleteLoc)
```

I thought deleteLoc will disappear after this dequeue method ends but why add this? This is not my code so I'm curious. Does it obliterate the memory that deleteLoc contained or queue->front ?
Isn't the point is to make the data itself be disappeared?

Thank you.

```
bool dequeue(H* queue ,void* itemPtr)
{
    node* deletecLoc;
    if (!queue->count)
        return false;
    *itemPtr = queue->front->dataPtr;
    deleteLoc = queue->front;
    if (queue->count == 1)
        queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    else
        queue->front = queue->front->next;
    (queue->count)--;
    free(deleteLoc);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: First of all, `NULL` is the symbolic name of a null *pointer*. Secondly, in C everything non-zero is considered true, while zero is false. That explains what the logical negation operator `!` does, if `queue->count` is zero (and therefore false) then `!queue->count` will be true. All of this should have been known if you [read a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Please start there.

Comment: And please keep it to one question per question. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder whether
>
> ```
> if (queue->count == 0)
> ```
>
> can be used instead of
>
> ```
> if (!queue->count)
> ```

Yes, you can always express an implicit comparison to zero with an explicit comparison and vice versa.

> Are the `NULL` and `0` used in the same way?

In the context of implicit comparison to zero performed by `if`, `while`, and other control statements, comparison to `NULL` and comparison to zero behave in the same way.

> what does this do?
>
> ```
> free(deleteLoc)
> ```

To understand this you need to look through the code of `enqueue` and find a call to `malloc` or `calloc`. Essentially, `free` is an "undo" for `malloc`, telling the system that you are no longer using the memory allocated to it dynamically.

> Does it obliterate the memory that `deleteLoc` contained or `queue->front`

It may or may not change the content of the memory pointed to by `deleteLoc`, but it does not matter, because that memory becomes off-limits to your program: accessing it after a call to `free` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`if (queue->count == 0)` will do the exact same thing as `if (!queue->count)` because in C if something evaluates to `0`, if you treat it as a boolean it will evaluate to `false`.

In this context, yes, `NULL` and `0` will achieve the same thing. `NULL` refers to a *null pointer*, whereas 0 is usually the number zero, but they evaluate to the same thing.

Finally, `free` will get rid of memory allocated earlier. You've not shown all of the code but somewhere in the `insert` function, there will be a `malloc` (or similar function) which allocates memory for you to store your node in. `Free` gets rid of that memory and you need to call it when you are done with a node.

Comment: Actually in C it's common for `NULL` to be of type `void *`. Which is (semantically) very different from the `int` value `0`. The two should not really be mixed.